# Android: why is BufferedReader reading past the EOF?

Tags: android, android-emulator, bufferedreader, eof, garbage

I was reading in a dictionary of words in my Android app in the emulator and caught the BufferedReader reading past the EOF.  Why would it be doing that?  Here is the code using the BufferedReader.

```
public void populateWordsTable(FileReader reader ) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String s;
        while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            String[] words = s.split(":");
            if ( words.length < 2 || words[1].isEmpty() || words[1].length() < 2 ) {
                System.out.println( "Skipping: " + s );
                continue; // only want words with lots of ending variations? to save time
            }
            String word  = words[0];
            System.out.println("adding: " + s);
            cv.put( WORD , word );
            db.insert( WORD_TABLE , null, cv);
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println( "Oh no, an exception: " + ex );
    }
    finally {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the output showing it reading past the EOF for some reason:

note that "zyrian: zyrians," is the last line of the dictionary file I'm reading in from.

```
10-28 18:51:37.933: I/System.out(4473): adding: zygospore: zygospores, 
10-28 18:51:38.056: I/System.out(4473): adding: zygote: zygotes, 
10-28 18:51:38.155: I/System.out(4473): Skipping: zygotene: 
10-28 18:51:38.174: I/System.out(4473): Skipping: zygotic: 
10-28 18:51:38.174: I/System.out(4473): Skipping: zyloprim: 
10-28 18:51:38.174: I/System.out(4473): Skipping: zymase: 
10-28 18:51:38.174: I/System.out(4473): adding: zymogen: zymogens, 
10-28 18:51:38.284: I/System.out(4473): Skipping: zymoid: 
10-28 18:51:38.328: I/System.out(4473): Skipping: zymology: 
10-28 18:51:38.328: I/System.out(4473): Skipping: zymolysis: 
10-28 18:51:38.364: I/System.out(4473): Skipping: zymosis: 
10-28 18:51:38.364: I/System.out(4473): Skipping: zymotic: 
10-28 18:51:38.364: I/System.out(4473): Skipping: zymurgy: 
10-28 18:51:38.384: I/System.out(4473): adding: zyrian: zyrians, 
10-28 18:51:38.604: I/System.out(4473): Skipping: PK?????Y\A?????????????????????????????res/layout/activity_main.xml?TMkA~'??n??4??(x?T?????bE???,6?awb
10-28 18:51:38.604: I/System.out(4473): adding: ??P????????k?t?k?:????<????}?y??@??#??5???("??3??[??##???O????B!l??nx?Gl?-?J?O?A???8q?hG07????? ?;$
10-28 18:51:38.716: D/dalvikvm(4473): GC_CONCURRENT freed 396K, 55% free 2658K/5831K, external 929K/1038K, paused 8ms+7ms
10-28 18:51:38.788: I/System.out(4473): Skipping: #M??????tR(?è???n???I?',?ZI??mJ???o/]?,?q??u5? m??8\?F??4?Bh?f?[.?(E?}??U?0 6???????/??@?<!?b
10-28 18:51:38.788: I/System.out(4473): adding: q?+?R?#?{ ~?????S?g?2??u0??g????e"?????????:?t??'4m
10-28 18:51:38.866: I/System.out(4473): Skipping: M?I?Ss?kn#W?4?\?(i?????8??}*?P?5%?s??u8??!??5?9???7??!?Z?YKS??yd5?=[??d\i?W[f>X??|?r??f%M?????0??{?K?t??y???g3~E
10-28 18:51:38.866: I/System.out(4473): Skipping: ??SC?=,?????|???1?^Rh?9???]??ngg?_w??;?<_??\???sS?yE??L?x???;?~??byp7g8??
```

etc.

Thank you for any clues

**Update**:

speakingcode and full.stack.ex asked me to show how the FileReader got created.

I followed another thread about how to get a text file into the "assets" folder  uncompressed by giving it a false extension.   Like so...

```
 public void populateTables() {
      //TODO: is there a way to get the assets from the application, or does it have
  // to happen in an Activity?

      ThisVsThatApplication myapp = (ThisVsThatApplication)getApplicationContext();
      WordsDB db = myapp.getDB();
      if ( db == null ) {
        myapp.printerizer( "The database was not initialized.");
        return;
      }
      try {
        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("dictionary.jpg");
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());
            db.populateWordsTable(reader);
      } 
      catch ( IOException ex ) {
        System.out.println( "Oh noes an exception: " + ex );
      }
  }
```

so, maybe the FileReader thinks this is a binary file?  I wonder if I can tell it it is a text file directly....

Using the code suggested by full.stack.ex, made this change here and it works!

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("dictionary.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
db.populateWordsTable(br);
```

Thank you

Comment: have yuo made sure there isn't gibberish at the end of the file? also do you have the code showing the instantiation of the FileReader object you're passing to the method?

Comment: Where is the file coming from? How did you open it to get the reader? How about adb pull?

Comment: @speakingcode:  Yes, it's just a text file, nothing at the end.

Comment: @speakingcode:  Yes, I think you have maybe identified that is where the problem is.  I followed a thread about tricking the apk creator into allowing my text file uncompressed by giving it a false extension.  So I named the textfile: dictionary.jpg to get it into the apk uncompressed.  So, maybe the FileReader is treating it like a binary file?   I wonder if I can tell it to treat it as a text file...

Comment: @full.stack.ex:  I added the code that shows where this came from in the Update above... I will ponder adb pull too thx

Comment: Why?! Why openFd? Why not just open? I've just looked into the code of a few projects - open works just fine on, say, HTML files, i.e., texts.

Comment: ... and no tricks with extensions.

Comment: @full.stack.ex.  Hmm.  Okay, please send those links if you can.  When I didn't try to trick the extension, I got the error:  FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up the comments, here's a piece of production code with some irrelevant parts removed and some kept. As you can see, we had some subdirectories in the assets. Please note that it uses method **open** rather than **openFd**. I may still be missing something, but this stuff has been working for quite a while.

```
public InputStream openInputStream(String inFileName) throws IOException {
    AssetManager assetManager = myContext.getAssets();
    String separator = "/";
    if ("".equals(getInputAssetSubdirectory())) {
        separator = "";
    }
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(assetManager.open(getInputAssetSubdirectory() + separator + inFileName), BUFFER_SIZE);
    return in;
}
```